# Calendar security

Tags: calendar

I am no fan of google services, but in the meantime until I mount my own CalDav server I still need some kind of calendar synchronization between my devices.

I tried then to connect Elementary OS default calendar app to my gmail account, but when I did so start receiving warning messages from Google that the service that was trying to access my data is unsafe and the request was blocked. Anyone know what kind of security flaw the calendar app is presenting? Are there any plans to repair it?

Comment: elementary apps use standard protocols like IMAP or CalDAV to sync with online accounts, while some providers, like Google, prefer OAuth for authentication. Google considers all the other standard protocols "less secure" (although there is little evidence that they are insecure) and complains laudly when OAuth is not used. There is some work in progress to support OAuth in elementary OS, I think, but it's not ready yet.

Answer (score 0):

Elementary and Google dont play together, you need to create a 1 off password the get the two together.
follow this link and ti will get you going.
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en